# Remote login desktop environment

Tags: authentication, client, remote-desktop, dedicated-server

So here's the deal, I recently started to get into the whole server world and seriously genius  and practical! I started slow with file sharing and then remote login. I now can manage to login into my server with ssh and it's great but sometimes command line interface is not enough for what I want to do. So I remembered that in my university students where able to login with their university-account into any computer connected to university server, wether it was Windows, FreeBSD or any GNU/Linux distribution such as Debian or Fedora. So I'm trying to do the same at home. My server is up and running on Debian now I now want to be able to login to my server with a desktop environment, like in my university. The client I'm using is MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Lion. But I don't know what protocol is that or how to set it up any clue?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is VNC (Virtual Network Computing).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing